# Bandwidth test, delay test using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, bandwidth

I want to make a python script that tests the bandwidth of a connection. I am thinking of downloading/uploading a file of a known size using urllib2, and measuring the time it takes to perform this task. I would also like to measure the delay to a given IP address, such as is given by pinging the IP. Is this possible using urllib2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PyCurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) for this. [curl_easy_getinfo](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) gives info about:
`CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME, CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME, CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could download an empty file to measure the delay. You measure more the only the network delay, but the difference should be too big I expect.