# How to check network bandwidth with Python?

Tags: python, bandwidth, ping

As asked, I would like my script to check network bandwidth giving me any idea how fast user can surf through web. Is there any library, which allows me to specify size of package to be send and gives ping time or whatever?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bandwidth test, delay test using urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280391/bandwidth-test-delay-test-using-urllib2)

Comment: This is not solved yet.. you are being mis-leaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python/317206#317206) mentions a Python implementation of `ping` that returns the ICMP packet's round-trip time. You can use the improved code from the comment: https://gist.github.com/255009.

But note that since it uses raw sockets, your Python script will need to run as `root`.

Comment: Thank You for an answer. I have figured out that websites which are not loaded properly with my script, use ajax, so using anything from Your post would be just multipling timeout. Anyway I hope it might be useful for someone else.

Comment: Ping can provide the latency, not bandwidth. You can measure the quality of road with `ping` not the width of the road.